# CentOS 8 auditd AVC denials message flood caused by denied setuid

Tags: linux, selinux, centos-8, setuid, auditd

Today my CentOS 8 suddenly frozen and not responding to user inputs.
When I tried to login from console, I saw messages like these:

```
audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
```

Booting into rescue mode using rd.break method mentioned in https://www.linuxtechi.com/boot-centos-8-rhel-8-single-user-mode/ and looking for the cause which made backlog limit exceeded using steps mentioned in https://www.hungred.com/how-to/backlog-limit-exceeded-error-freeze-centos-6/, I temporarily disable SELinux which caused the AVC message flood and reboot to a running system.

The AVC report shows that the `auditd` process is denied `setuid` as shown below:

```
AVC Report
===============================================================
# date time comm subj syscall class permission obj result event
===============================================================
1. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38155
2. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38156
3. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38157
4. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38158
5. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38159
6. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38160
7. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38161
8. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38162
9. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38163
10. 09/02/2020 16:21:49 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 38164
.
.
.
187963. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39782
187964. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39783
187965. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39784
187966. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39785
187967. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39786
187968. 09/02/2020 16:57:04 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 39787
```

Anyone might know what caused the denials and know a solution for the problem ?
Could it be caused by bad/failed update or some hacking attempt?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Im getting the exact same thing today on Centos 7

9492. 03/09/20 11:42:58 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 449300257
9493. 03/09/20 11:42:58 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 449300258
9494. 03/09/20 11:42:58 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 449300259
9495. 03/09/20 11:42:58 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 449300260
9496. 03/09/20 11:42:58 auditd system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 0 capability setuid system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 denied 44930026

Comment: Did you also have palo alto installed?